# How to Connect Airflow, running on Docker, to GCS

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-storage

I am new to Docker and Airflow. I have created a project for learning purpose. My Airflow setup on Docker works fine for a simple task that prints "Hello World", However I wanted to run a task that loads a file from my local folder on my machine to a Google Cloud Storage bucket and this time it throws the following error:

```
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 429, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 789, in __init__
    f"Invalid arguments were passed to {self.__class__.__name__} (task_id: {task_id}). "
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator (task_id: task1). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'google_cloud_storage_conn_id': 'google_cloud_default'}
```

My DAG task looks like the following:

```
from airflow import DAG
import pendulum
from airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs import FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

with DAG(dag_id="demo", schedule_interval='@daily',catchup=False,tags=["example"],default_args={'owner': 'DP','start_date': pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC")}) as dag:

    task_1 = FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        src = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\export_occupancy.csv',
        dst = 'sample',
        bucket = 'my-bucket',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
        task_id = "task1")

task_1
```

Can you please tell me if I am missing something here? Thanks :)

Comment: did you configure this connection (google_cloud_storage_conn_id) ? the key and secret